Projectile Motion Optimization - Minimum Final Velocity?
I'm doing a project on the physics of basketball and wanted to find the optimal angle of release for a free throw (the basket is 3.05 m tall and 4.572 m away). The optimal angle would be the angle at which the ball's final velocity when it hits the rim is minimal. I know that x velocity is constant so I focused on the Y. I couldn't get past differentiating $-9.8t + v_0 sin (\theta)$ and setting it to zero. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The important part is that the ball goes through the hoop -- so maybe start with writing down equations that let you figure out if and when that happens.

The $x$ velocity of the ball is constant from the time it leaves your hand until it hits the basket. But you are considering different ways to make the shot, and as you vary the angle of release you will also need to vary the $x$ component of the velocity at release. That is, we're talking about things you can vary before the ball leaves your hand.

What is the height of the point above the ground from where the ball is thrown?

There are at least two missing measurements in this question. One is the height from which the ball is released (which should be a variable, since the height of basketball players is not standardized). Another is the distance from the backboard to the middle of the hoop. You could also consider the horizontal position of the point of release relative to the free-throw line. Presumably you want a basketball player to make the shot, not have a tiny cannon sitting on the free throw line that fires a tiny cannonball that must hit the point where the hoop is attached to the backboard.

As you mentioned, the horizontal velocity ($v_x=v_0cos\theta$) is constant. So the time it takes to reach the hoop is the distance divided by the velocity,
$t=\frac{4.572}{v_0cos\theta}$.
Now we focus on the vertical travel of the ball. The minimum vertical velocity is zero, at the peak. We have
$y=3.05$,
$u_y=v_0sin\theta$,
$v_y=0$,
$a_y=-9.8$,
$t=\frac{4.572}{v_0cos\theta}$.
I will let you fill in some details, but using the equation $v^2=u^2+2ay$ gives
$v_0sin\theta=7.73$
and the equation $y=vt-\frac{1}{2}at^2$ gives
$v_0cos\theta = 5.80$.
So we find $tan\theta= 1.33$ and thus $\theta=53$ degrees.

Thanks for the answer, but I was confused on why vy is 0. I want to minimize the vertical velocity when the ball hits the rim when y position is 3.05

@JiamuYue What do you mean by minimize then?

@ljfirth The part of the question that appears to say we only minimize $y$ velocity is apparently based on a mistaken idea about how to solve the original problem. The first sentence of the question clearly states that it is the velocity (not just the $y$ velocity) that is to be minimized. Besides, reaching the basket with all the velocity in the $x$ direction and none in the $y$ direction is one way to be sure that the free throw will not go in the basket.

@DavidK With no other information about what it means for the ball to go "through" the basket, this abstraction seems reasonable (otherwise we need to get into the sizes of the ball and basket if and how the ball rebounds off the rim). With only x and no y velocity, the ball just clears the rim and the bottom of the ball crosses the plane of the rim into the basket - the ball must go "in" the basket, even if it may not go all the way through before it hits the back of the rim.

@NuclearHoagie While technically true for a rather strained meaning of the word "in", this line of investigation is useless for the OP's project. It might be possible to incorporate it in a humorous satire like the one about measuring the height of a building with a barometer.

With a problem like this, I find it preferable to assign names to the various distances and other constants and only plug in the actual numbers at the end, when I have a formula for the answer.
That way if you find later that one of your numbers wasn't quite right, you don't have to work through the entire solution process all over again.
So let's say that the target (the center of the hoop, or whatever point you think is good to aim at to make the free throw) is $h$ distance vertically above the point of release of the ball and $L$ distance horizontally from the point of release.
Also, suppose the acceleration of gravity is $g.$
Let's also suppose the angle of release is $\theta.$ This is the quantity whose optimal value you eventually want to find.
The next step is to realize that you only really have one degree of freedom in this problem. If you choose an angle $\theta$ and you release with too little velocity, you'll miss. If you release with too much velocity, you'll miss. You need just the right velocity to reach the center of the hoop, not overshoot or undershoot.
So the thing is to decide that no matter what, the ball must hit the basket.
Then whatever angle $\theta$ you choose, there is precisely one correct initial velocity $v_0$ as a function of $\theta.$
Having chosen a $\theta,$ once you find that $v_0,$ the entire trajectory is determined.
In particular, you can then find out what the total velocity of the ball is when it reaches the hoop.
There is still the big question of how to figure out what function of $\theta$ gives you the correct initial velocity $v_0$ so you can hit the target.
But once you figure out that function, you can also figure out the function of $\theta$ that gives the final velocity at the hoop.
And then you just need to figure out how to minimize that velocity as a function of $\theta,$ which I think you know how to do.
And that's a solution method. If I went into more details, I'm afraid it would spoil the exercise.

Generally, when looking at optimization problems, it sometimes pays to pick some other parameter (not the one that whose value you want to know in the end) as the one that represents your single degree of freedom.
For example, for the free throw, you could choose the total time in flight (from release to hoop) as the parameter. Or you could choose the $x$ velocity as a parameter.
There are a few other even more obscure choices that might work.
Of course if you choose anything except $\theta$ as your parameter, you have to minimize the final velocity as a function of that parameter
and then find the desired launch angle $\theta$ as a function of the optimal value of that parameter. So you might find it conceptually easiest to just stick with $\theta$ as the thing that everything else is a function of.
I don't think any of the alternatives will actually be much easier to work with, anyway, for this particular problem.
Regardless of what parameter you decide to use for optimization,
there are facts about trajectories of this kind that would enable you to simplify the calculations. For example, if you can compute the initial velocity, you don't need to compute the final velocity, because minimizing the initial velocity also minimizes the final velocity. (The difference in the squares of these velocities is a constant.)
Another simplification you can make is that you don't need to work out the complete trajectory. You just need to hit the target.

Suppose the ball is released from point $P$ at an angle $\theta$ above horizontal. If there were no gravity, the ball would continue in a straight line to point $A.$ But because of gravity, the ball falls to the point $B$ below the straight-line path.
The distance the ball falls relative to the straight line
(the distance from $A$ to $B,$ which you can easily find as a function of $\theta$) is the same as the distance an initially stationary object falls in time $T,$ where $T$ is the total flight time.
So it is relatively easy to get $T$ as a function of $\theta,$ and then find the initial velocity.
Just remember that you cannot vary $\theta$ while keeping $t$ and $v_0$ constant.
Any variation in $\theta$ requires you to make an adjustment in launch velocity $v_0,$ which generally leads to a change in total flight time.

We can simplify slightly by recognizing that every trajectory ending with the ball in the basket sees the same net change in potential/kinetic energy. Minimizing the initial velocity/KE will also minimize the final velocity/KE - we just need to minimize the initial velocity with respect to theta, and can skip the step of describing the final velocity as a function of theta (although it's certainly valid).

@NuclearHoagie It is true that minimizing the initial velocity is as good as minimizing the final velocity. I was initially just trying to go for the basic idea of this as an optimization problem, without using particular insights from physics. But that hint was worth adding to the answer. I ended up adding another hint as well.
